# Why sound asset can't be referenced from code in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I've dragged [resources](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/01/SpriteKitSimpleGameResources.zip) into Sounds.xcassets folder as below:

[image]

Then I intended to add it into my demo game, with code snippet:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        ...

        let backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "background-music-aac.caf")
        backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
        addChild(backgroundMusic)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        ...

        runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("pew-pew-lei.caf", waitForCompletion: false))
    }
}
```

Neither of them worked, with error message: **SpriteKitSimpleGame[29290:927376] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "pew-pew-lei.caf"**

The two sound files are `background-music-aac.caf` and `pew-pew-lei.caf`, could anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to change that sound with another caf , or change with mp3, aac...?

Comment: If you are using assets, you do not include the `.caf` in `fileNamed`,  and using hyphens may be a bad thing also, not positive on this, but it may affect the asset naming convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the asset folder, do not include any extension in the file name.

The asset looks for a meta file that contains the actual file name, so it is possible to alias your sounds that do not reflect the file name, so make sure you use the alias in the atlas, and not the file name.

As per my old answer:

I believe you need to use NSDataAsset for this. As KnightOfDragon has so kindly pointed out this seems to only apply for AVFoundation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1913/_index.html

Seems easier to just drag them directly into your project.

Comment: What's the difference between merely dragging them directly into the project, and into the xcassets?

Comment: This is only for AVFoundation, not for SKAudio I believe

Comment: So for SkAudio, the only way is not putting sounds in assets folder? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: @JasonZhu, check my comment,  you can use assets

Comment: nooooo, do not accept this if what I said is the answer  That will only confuse people,  @crashoverride777 if what I said is the answer, could you please change your answer to reflect it for future people.